# Removing the bottom bar from a window + AIR App

Tags: flex4, air, flashbuilder4

Hey there-  I need to remove a bottom bar from my FlashBuilder4 AIR App on a MAC.  I've set the config.xml file to this:

```
<systemChrome>none</systemChrome>
<transparent>true</transparent>
```

While this removes the window bgcolor, top bar and border, I still receive a bottom bar in my app.  How do I remove it?  Thanks, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

```
<mx:WindowedApplication
...
    showStatusBar="false"
...
```

Comment: But if you do that you remove the ability to resize the application. What did you do to keep resize option?

Comment: If I remember right, resize ability is removed with systemChrome, which disables window border.